# My django site stopped working after a crash and the errors make no sense

Tags: python, django

I have a large django 3.1 project that was working as of my last git push last Sunday. After that push, I started working on some bash deployment scripts and had a system crash (Ubuntu) related to testing these scripts (bash is not my forte!). I rebooted the machine, and continued working. I started running some tests on the django code and low and behold the working code in my django project is broken in a very weird way.

**Weirdness #1 - imports not working**

In one of my save_model functions in the `admin.py` of one of my apps, I have this line, which on Sunday was working.

```
obj2.computed_sha256 = image_processing_utils.compute_sha256(f)
```

I got a django error message that `image_processing_utils` was not defined. However, there is an import statement at the top of the admin file `from image_processing import image_processing_utils`. I copied the import statement to the line above the `obj2.computed_sha256 = image_processing_utils.compute_sha256(f)` and the save_model function worked correctly.

**Weirdness #2 - database values incorrect**

I ran another `admin` test where a `post_delete` signal is called. I have these lines:

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Face)
def auto_delete_face_metadata(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # delete the Face metadata when the Face object is deleted
    doc_id = instance.document.document_id
    doc_metadata = DocumentMetaData.objects.filter(document_id=doc_id).first()
    metadata = doc_metadata.metadata
```

I get an error message that `doc_metadata` is `None`, so it cannot access the field `metadata`. However, when I step through the code, the `doc_id` is correct (3056), and if I run this code in a ./manage.py shell in the same virtual environment, the field metadata is there and has the values I expected. I also verified that the data is in the database using the mysql shell.

```
>>> from memorabilia.models import DocumentMetaData
>>> DocumentMetaData.objects.get(document_id=3056)
<DocumentMetaData: originals/photo/Rady_Evie_Mary_at_Jackrabbit_Dec_6_2001.tiff>
>>> len(DocumentMetaData.objects.get(document_id=3056).metadata)
15
>>>
```

I cloned my git repo with the code from Sunday to another directory, and used Meld to look for  differences between the cloned repo directory and the development code, and there are no differences except in the deployment scripts I was working on when the system crashed, and those differences are correct. I use Wing Pro 7 as my IDE. I have rebooted my machine and still have the same issues.

I would really appreciate any help you can provide in figuring out why code that should work is not broken.

Mark

Comment: I have no idea, but my suspicions for the local code throwing weird errors would be that some environment variables like $PATH or [`$PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) are somehow goofed. Also I'd clear caches, like `__pycache__`.

Comment: When you say clear caches, do you mean delete __pycache__ dirs? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, they contain compiled python byte-code. It will be refilled when you run the code.

Comment: I could be completely off track here, though. It may be something else.

Comment: Thanks again for your idea of removing all the `__pycache__` dirs. No change in the weirdness.